# Convert a 16-bit image from rgb to Lab without losing precision

Tags: python, image, 16-bit, lab-color-space

i have a 16 bit image in PhoPhoto RGB color space.For equalizzation I want to convert it in Lab colorspace and then equalize L-channel without losing precision. I have used skimage.color.rgb2lab but this convert image in float64.
help me!!

Answer (score 0):

skimage version of rgb2lab uses floating point input where the color range is 0-1. You can normalize your 16bit image to this range and use the rgb2lab routine.